# Why did Thomasin give in so easily?

Tags: the-witch

To avoid spoilers of the end of the movie, I reduced the title, originally I intended to ask:

> Why did Thomasin give in to Devil so easily

Which is the real question here - at the end of movie, I expected here to try to get revenge. I thought she will try to stab Black Phillip. Of course, killing a goat doesn't kill the Devil and would probably lead to her demise. But it would be expected flow of events.

Instead, she suddenly turned the sides. Why? Was she the Witch all along, just not aware of it herself?

Comment: I don't agree that she gave in easily or suddenly. The entire movie was building up to that ending. She went with the "if you can't beat em, join em" philosophy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this happened because of the way her parents treated her. And maybe that's what the whole movie is all about. When your own people treat you bad and don't trust you, they make you turn to things you wouldn't initially want to turn to.

So Thomasin's parents treated her awfully and never trusted her or listened to her and that lead her to give in to the devil although she initially didn't want to.

Comment: I think this is half right.  The other half is... what are her options at this point?  Her entire family is dead or missing, and she would be the key suspect (in fact she DID kill one of them, in self-defense, but who would believe that at this point?)  She pretty much has limited choices now... join the witches, or try to go back to civilization and eventually get captured and tried for murder and probably convicted and executed, or try to live alone in the wild and probably either get captured anyway or die alone.  She doesn't have a whole lot of realistic life options now.

Comment: Yes but satan is supposed to be the ultimate evil and you don't join the ultimate evil like this. I agree that she had no options but she had to be pushed by the things her own people did to her. The reason why I insist is because when she finally gives in to the devil, she doesn't seem to be hesitant about or having regrets.

Comment: Well, in theory you could ask that about anyone who follows / worships Satan, but those people still exist.  Probably a multitude of reasons.  I'd think the main one was rebellion against her religious family: they branded her a witch and were potentially going to murder her.  If you see two sides, religion and rebellion against religion, and the religion side was about to murder you, maybe rebellion starts to look a bit nicer?  Especially since it offers such obvious benefits NOW... not only staying alive, but living "deliciously". Can worry about the afterlife later.

Comment: I like your theory. I wonder if Thomasin would become a rebel against her religious family if they treated her right though. What I am saying is that I think the cause was her family treating her bad and that their religious beliefs played a minor role.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps the religious beliefs were a scapegoat, but they played a pretty large role in the ultimate turning against her and branding her a witch.

Comment: @AndrewWhatever Yes I agree!

Answer (score 2):

She does not *give in*, **she bargains.**

What canst thou give?

She chose the Devil, and the powers he would give her. Riches, both corporeal and ethereal. When she speaks to Black Phillip to sign his ledger, she goes to him; not the other way around. She wants to become a witch at this point.

Previously she was scared, but now; an outcast with no family who is believed to be a witch anyway? what does she have to lose?